# Electron app restarts automatically after calling fs.writeFile method

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, writefile, node.js-fs

I have a problem with my electron app. I'm writing an app that creates CV's using data that user entered to it. I don't know how to prevent automatically restart after calling a fs.writeFile method. It causes any errors or anything like that, just restart. I installed all fs files using terminal and also included this line of code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
```

That's the function which generates the problem:

```
const generatePDF = function () {

  fs.writeFile('database.json', JSON.stringify(userData), (err) => {

    if (err) console.log(err);
})};
```

I've tried to look for some answers in google but I didn't find anything, thanks for all your help, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: How are you running the project? It seems like a file watcher is automatically restarting the project when files update.

Comment: Im using console and this command npx electronmon .

Comment: Oh idk if you ask how I start app or how I store my files maybe?

Comment: As expected. Electronmon sees a file change so it restarts the project. You tell electronmon to not restart when "database.json" changes. This can be done via a pattern in your package.json. [As shown in their example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electronmon)

Comment: Okay it seems helpful but I really don't understand this text, where to find electronom object and what to write in it. I can find couple of package.json files in my project but any of them has electronom object

Comment: In your main `package.json` file (aka the one in the root directory), you can create `electronom` object, and add a pattern that prevent your app from restarting (in this case `database.json`).

Comment: Thank you guys, it's working perfectly :D